# Обрезать определенное значение в строке PHP

Tags: php, html

Есть строка

```
<h2 class="inset" _mce_style="text-align: center;" style="text-align: center;"><strong>По информации DW, дрезденская НПО передала  Антикоррупционному агентству Казахстана документы о счетах чиновников, на  которых за пределами республики лежат «грязные деньги». Что дальше?</strong></h2>
<p align="left"><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><br></p><p align="left"><strong><em>Восьмого декабря, за  трое суток до перевода на пост генерального прокурора республики, тогда еще  председатель казахстанского Агентства по делам государственной службы и  противодействию коррупции Кайрат Кожамжаров объявил о наличии черного списка,  включающего имена бывших чиновников, которые прячут в офшорах миллиарды  долларов. По словам Кожамжарова, в списке 53 человека, часть из них скрывается  за границей, а сумма выведенных ими из Казахстана средств оценивается в более  чем 8 миллиардов долларов.</em></strong></p>
<p align="center"><strong></strong></p>
```

Как из этой строки получить

```
<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

и сохранить ее в переменную?

делаю так

```
$patt = '~<img[^>]*>~';
preg_match($patt, $str, $a);
echo $a;
```

Но что то не работает, так же как удалить в теге img атрибут style и атрибут class

Comment: В переменной `$a` у вас массив должен быть, а не строка.

Comment: Не `echo $a;`, а `var_dump($a);` - и все работает. Желательно инициализировать переменную `$a`, как массив `$a=[];` или `$a = array();` - если `php` ниже 5.4.

Comment: Спасибо можете написать как правильный ответ

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/584ab6de6d490cfcca0cffcf8982f7dea7791c81

Comment: @duddeniska в каменте выше полный вариант (с удалением). Я со смартфона его написал, и скопировать сюда (если нужно) смогу только позже, как буду за ПК.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str='<h2 class="inset" _mce_style="text-align: center;" style="text-align: center;"><strong>По информации DW, дрезденская НПО передала  Антикоррупционному агентству Казахстана документы о счетах чиновников, на  которых за пределами республики лежат «грязные деньги». Что дальше?</strong></h2>
    <p align="left"><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><br></p><p align="left"><strong><em>Восьмого декабря, за  трое суток до перевода на пост генерального прокурора республики, тогда еще  председатель казахстанского Агентства по делам государственной службы и  противодействию коррупции Кайрат Кожамжаров объявил о наличии черного списка,  включающего имена бывших чиновников, которые прячут в офшорах миллиарды  долларов. По словам Кожамжарова, в списке 53 человека, часть из них скрывается  за границей, а сумма выведенных ими из Казахстана средств оценивается в более  чем 8 миллиардов долларов.</em></strong></p>
    <p align="center"><strong></strong></p>';

$patt = '~<img[^>]+>~';
preg_match($patt, $str, $a);
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

[strip_tags(string $str [, string $allowable_tags ])](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) - удалит теги в строке и оставит указанный вторым аргументом. Недостаток - оставит контент удалённых тегов. Поэтому такой подход стоит использовать для удаления тегов-обёрток цели без вложенного контента.

```
$img = strip_tags($str, '<img>');
```

[preg-match(string $pattern,array $results)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) - найдёт в строке по регулярному выражению, результат вернёт в массив $results. Вложенность контента в теги-обёртки, в данном  случае, не имеет значения.

```
preg_match('#(<img.*)#', $str, $results); // $results[0]
```

> "так же как удалить в теге img атрибут style и атрибут class" - duddeniska, stackoverflow, 27.12.17

Если задача предусматривает повторные вызовы и несколько действий, как в вопросе, т.е. достать тег и удалить при необходимости некие его атрибуты, думаю правильно запаковать логику в функцию:

```
$str = '<h2><strong>Контент</strong></h2><p><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><br></p><p><strong><em>Восьмого декабря, ... более  чем 8 миллиардов долларов.</em></strong></p><p"><strong></strong></p>';

$processed_tag = extractTag($str, 'img', array('class','style'));

function extractTag($string, $target, $params = []) {
    preg_match("#(<$target.*)#", $string, $match);  
    $return = $match[0];
    if($params) {
        foreach($params as $attr) {     
            $return = preg_replace('#\s' . $attr . '=".*?"#', "", $return); 
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сперва **получить** тег *img*, а потом его обработать:

```
$str ='<h2 class="inset" _mce_style="text-align: center;" style="text-align: center;"><strong>По информации DW, дрезденская НПО передала  Антикоррупционному агентству Казахстана документы о счетах чиновников, на  которых за пределами республики лежат «грязные деньги». Что дальше?</strong></h2>
<p align="left"><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><br></p><p align="left"><strong><em>Восьмого декабря, за  трое суток до перевода на пост генерального прокурора республики, тогда еще  председатель казахстанского Агентства по делам государственной службы и  противодействию коррупции Кайрат Кожамжаров объявил о наличии черного списка,  включающего имена бывших чиновников, которые прячут в офшорах миллиарды  долларов. По словам Кожамжарова, в списке 53 человека, часть из них скрывается  за границей, а сумма выведенных ими из Казахстана средств оценивается в более  чем 8 миллиардов долларов.</em></strong></p>
<p align="center"><strong></strong></p>';

preg_match('~<img[^>]+>~', $str, $img);
$img = preg_replace('~(?<!src=)"[^"]+"[^">]*~', '', $img[0]);

echo $img;
```

Результат:

```
<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg">
```